# Vectorized function with 2d integral inside

Tags: arrays, matlab, function

I'm having trouble trying to write a 2d function with vectorized inputs that has an integral inside.

My function is as follows:

```
thick = 40e-9; 
overlap = (@(E,T)integral2(@(x,y)exp(E.*T.*abs(x-y)),0,thick,0,thick));
```

If I call the function with scalar inputs, e.g. overlap(1,1), this works fine.

```
overlap(1,1)
ans = 1.6000e-15
```

However, if I call the function with vector inputs for E and T, e.g. `E=1:1:10` and `T=1:1:10`, this does not work. I get the following:

```
Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Does anyone know how to make this work with vectorized inputs? I'm looking for a way to do it in the inline function itself, without for loops.

Answer (score 0):

The error refers to `E` and `T` having different shape than `x` and `y`, presumably `integral2` passes arrays to `x` and `y`. This convenience function is not equipped to integrate array-valued functions, so it can freely use array-valued inputs as it sees fit.

There's an easy fix for your problem: move the exponentiation outside your integral:

```
>> overlap = @(E,T)integral2(@(x,y)exp(abs(x-y)),0,thick,0,thick).^(E.*T); 
>> overlap(1,1)                                                            

ans =

   1.6000e-15

>> overlap(E,T)                                                            

ans =

   1.0e-14 *

    0.1600    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

Not a very interesting result due to double-precision, but what matters is that the error has gone away and the result has the appropriate size.

But then you can easily see that you don't even have to integrate inside your function, since the integral no longer depends on your function inputs. This will make your function calls *much* faster:

```
>> thick = 1; % I don't like zeros
>> int = integral2(@(x,y)exp(abs(x-y)),0,thick,0,thick); % integrate only once!
>> overlap = @(E,T) int.^(E.*T);                        
>> overlap(1,1)

ans =

    1.4366

>> overlap(1:2,1:2)

ans =

    1.4366    4.2589
```